# time constant of rc circuit

Tags: remote-control, time-constant

How to calculate time constant of this circuit. .. and how the time constant of C1 and C2 are related
[image]

Comment: homework? What did you try till now? Where did you reach?

Comment: The time constant is called the RC product for a reason...

Comment: Please check you schematic. Like this there is no RC circuit. C1 must be between +  and -. Where is the output? what is this gap on the vertical line? etc...

Comment: @CuriousKP this is not homework.  I was trying to find capacitor voltage waveform Intuitively, I got the initial and final values ... But to draw for all time , I need time constant .